# Social sharing - post results to Twitter/Facebook/Google

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, twitter, google-plus

I'm developing one of those web apps, where you can take a test, or a poll, and then post your specific results to Twitter, Facebook, or Google Plus. What I'm wondering though, is: what's the best way to do it? I don't want to reinvent the wheel here, especially since the user can take the poll/test again, and the buttons would have to update with new text/titles based on the results.

Anyone know what might be a good solution for this, besides just refreshing the facebook/twitter/g+ buttons with the new results every time?

Answer (score 0):

You can write a FB/G+/Twitter application to do this using the appropriate API.

Comment: At least at references to the relevant APIs... From this answer, nothing can be learned as it is just stating the obvious.

Comment: Google+: https://developers.google.com/+/api/, Facebook: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/, Twitter: https://dev.twitter.com/start